# ST_contains taking too much time

Tags: postgresql, optimization, gis, postgis

I am trying to match latitude/longitude to a particular neighbor location using below query

```
create table address_classification as (
select distinct buildingid,street,city,state,neighborhood,borough
from master_data
join 
Borough_GEOM
on st_contains(st_astext(geom),coordinates) = 'true'
);
```

In this, coordinates is of below format

```
ST_GeometryFromText('POINT('||longitude||' '||latitude||')') as coordinates
```

and geom is of column type geometry.
i have already created indexes as below

```
CREATE INDEX coordinates_gix ON master_data USING GIST (coordinates);
CREATE INDEX boro_geom_indx ON Borough_GEOM USING gist(geom);
```

I have almost 3 million records in the main table and 200 geometric information in the GEOM table. Explain analyze of the query is taking so much time (2 hrs). 
Please let me know, how can i optimize this query.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'trying to match to a particular neighbor location?'. On your join condition why are you using st_astext()? 
I am assuming geom column is of geometry type. If it is, you can use `st_contains(geom, coordinates)`. You can also try `st_within` if it is to check whether the points lies inside a polygon or not.

Comment: Is buildingid unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- As mentioned in the comments, don't use `ST_AsText()`: that doesn't belong there. It's casting the geom to text, and then going back to geom. But, more importantly, that process is likely to fumble the index.
- If you're unique on only column then use `DISTINCT ON`, no need to compare the others.
- If you're unique on the ID column and your only joining to add selectivity then consider using `EXISTS`. Do any of these columns come from the `borough_GEOM` other than `geom`?

I'd start with something like this,

```
CREATE TABLE address_classification AS 
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (buildingid),
    buildingid,
    street,
    city,
    state,
    neighborhood,
    borough
  FROM master_data
  JOIN borough_GEOM
    ON ST_Contains(geom,coordinates);
```